# How can I save my typed text in the input field after pressing back button in mobile in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When i try to type something in the input field, the text shows up in the input field while typing. The moment I press the back button, it clears itself. If I enter the done button or press the OK button in input space at the top of the keyboard, then only it saves the text. Unlike android studio, input doesn't saves the text dynamically. I know that clearing the field on escape is made by design in unity. I followed a thread - pushing-back-button-escape-reverts-text-in-input-field, but there I couldn't find a proper answer. I also saw Esc Key Issue with Input Field in unity forum. But couldn't find a solution.

I have tried putting this to my code

```
InputField textToSend;
string stringEdit = "";
public void OnEditting()
{
    if (!Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        stringEdit = textToSend.text;
    }
}

public void OnEndEdit()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        textToSend.text = stringEdit;
    }
}
```

Please help me finding a solution for keeping the text after hitting the back button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
textToSend.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { OnValueChangesInputField(); })

public void OnValueChangesInputField()
{
   //Dynamic Text, get the string as it is being types
   string dynamicText = textToSend.text;
}
```

Comment: Hey Azemda, thanks for your response. dynamicText variable is storing the text but the moment I press the back button, text gets erased.

Comment: Back button in PC or android? When you press the back button, does the whole string that was typed gets erased or just the last character that was typed?

Comment: back button of android. the whole string gets erased. While debugging, while typing characters in the input field, characters gets stored in the dynamicText but when I press escape, the whole string gets erased. So, I tried with Input.GetKeydown(Keycode.Escape), it worked for Unity Editor but not for android.

Comment: Add a Debug.Log statement inside the if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) block inside the onEndEdit() function and check if it's showing up in abd logcat.